# How to open gnuradio's preset editor for "Embedded Python Blocks" on Windows?

Tags: python, gnuradio-companion

How to edit the python block of gnuradio on windows?
I have python IDE installed like PyScripter, Anaconda
But pressing 'use default' of 'open in editor'
The following two lines of error will run

```
>>> Unable to load the default editor. Please choose an editor.
```

```
>>> No editor selected.
```

Does anyone have the same situation as me?
If yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems that it does not work very well in Windows. See this thread on github: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/3567

Answer (score 0):

Any editor will do, I think. I just tried it with Visual Studio Code. The only gotcha is that the file dialogue box does not show hidden files by default, so you need to right click on the dialogue then select the option to show them, then navigate to the directory you want (it won't update without changing directories or maybe there's a refresh option.

If you have Python installed you could use Idle, use Visual Studio Code like me, or use the Notepad (or Notepad++ maybe as the other answer states). The imports of numpy and gnuradio are being flagged by Visual Studio Code as unresolved, so I'm not out of the woods yet, but as an editor it is working just fine.

Comment: Do you know how to make notepad++ (or any other) the default? Every time I open the "Open in Editor" on a python module in Gnuradio companion, I have to look for an editor again.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I found a solution.
Download notepad++ and when you press open in editor, find and select notepad++.exe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).